# reverse an array onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, reload, reverse

I have an array which displays info on a page. Id like to be able to reverse the order on click of a button.

.reverse() works but Im unsure how to call it on button click, and then refresh the display to show the reversed array?

my setup looks like:

included js file with my array (and code to display the array), my array is stored in a  variable (longer than this but just for show):

```
var images_gallery = [
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-1.jpg",
    },
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-2.jpg",
    },
    {
        image_src: "images/xmas-3.jpg",
    }
]

var image = $('<img>').addClass('librarian-gallery-img');
image.attr('src',images_gallery.image_src);
image.appendTo($('#gallery-container');
```

this displays my array (images) into my html. (simplified version, but thats the basics)

My issue is how to refresh the array and its display on the page

Comment: Please show your HTML so we can see how the DOM fits together.

Comment: Please provide us a jsfiddle with an example of your issue.

Comment: Try this... http://bit.ly/VnqnLK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `attr()` to change image src.

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
  images_gallery.reverse();
  $('#gallery-container img').attr('src', function( index){
      return images_gallery[index].image_src
  })

});
```

Using function argument of `attr()` provides access to index of element in collection

Comment: this works great, but im using a lightbox plugin on the images, which doesnt seem to load the new image when the src is switched, is there a way i can reload the lightbox.js aswell?

Comment: would depend on API of plugin you are using...there are many lighbox type plugins

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button#someID').click( function(event) {
    myArray.reverse();
});
```

Commenters are right though. Post your code so we can see things better. Note that reversing an underlying array of data isn't going to update the page, so you'll need to handle that bit yourself.